# Can't change TextView in Fragment from main Activity( with interface),

Tags: android, interface, nullpointerexception, textview, fragment

Although i have read similar post-questions, i havent found solution to my problem. As you can see in the title i cant change Textview in TextFragment.
i get this error:07-09 15:05:55.593 6441-6441/com.eguide.dimitris.campusguide E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-09 15:05:55.593 6441-6441/com.eguide.dimitris.campusguide E/AndroidRuntime: **java.lang.NullPointerException**
07-09 15:05:55.593 6441-6441/com.eguide.dimitris.campusguide E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.eguide.dimitris.campusguide.mainActivity$1.onVisitStart(mainActivity.java:66)

So i would appreciate any help.
Thanks in advance.

> mainActivity

```
public class mainActivity  extends Activity implements inter {
public PlaceManager placeManager;
public PlaceEventListener placeEventListener;
public String name;
TextView tt;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
    Gimbal.setApiKey(this.getApplication(), "5436462c-6400-48f4-b6af-e0ad2094550f");
    CommunicationManager.getInstance().startReceivingCommunications();
    tt=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.test);
}



@Override
public void respond(String data) {
    FragmentManager manager2=getFragmentManager();
    textFragment frag2= (textFragment) manager2.findFragmentById(R.id.text_fragment);
    frag2.changeText(data);
}

@Override
public void barstatus() {
    FragmentManager manager1=getFragmentManager();
    imageFragment frag1=(imageFragment) manager1.findFragmentById(R.id.image_fragment);
    frag1.changeStatus();
}

@Override
public void barstatus2() {
    FragmentManager manager1=getFragmentManager();
    imageFragment frag1=(imageFragment) manager1.findFragmentById(R.id.image_fragment);
    frag1.changeStatus2();
}


public void changestatus(){
    placeEventListener= new PlaceEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onVisitStart(Visit visit) {
            super.onVisitStart(visit);
            name=visit.getPlace().getName().toString();
            if (name!=null){
                respond(name);
                barstatus2();
            }
        }
    };
```

> textFragment

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class textFragment extends Fragment {

TextView text1;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.text_fragment, container,false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    text1 = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textF);
    text1.setText("Press Start button to find buildings near you");

}
public void changeText(String data){
    text1 = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textF);
    text1.setText(data.toString());

}

}
```

> imageFragment

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.transition.Visibility;
import android.view.ActionProvider;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;



public class imageFragment extends Fragment {

private ProgressBar bar;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_fragment,container,false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    bar=(ProgressBar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    bar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

}

public void changeStatus(){
    bar=(ProgressBar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

public void changeStatus2(){
    bar=(ProgressBar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    bar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
}
```

> interface

```
public interface inter {
public  void respond(String data);

public void barstatus();

public void barstatus2();
}
```

Guys also note tha i have tried and this in mainActivity but nothing changed.

```
inter inte;


public void changestatus(){
    placeEventListener= new PlaceEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onVisitStart(Visit visit) {
            super.onVisitStart(visit);
            name=visit.getPlace().getName().toString();
            if (name!=null){
                inte.respond(name);
                inte.barstatus2();
            }
        }
    };
```

EDIT:
if instead of

```
public void changestatus(){
placeEventListener= new PlaceEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onVisitStart(Visit visit) {
        super.onVisitStart(visit);
        name=visit.getPlace().getName().toString();
        if (name!=null){
            respond(name);
            barstatus2();
        }
    }
```

use

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    placeEventListener= new PlaceEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onVisitStart(Visit visit) {
            super.onVisitStart(visit);
            name=visit.getPlace().getName();
            if (name!=null){
                respond(name);
                barstatus2();
            }
        }
    };
```

i can make changes...can you explain me why??
i dont want this block of code running onStart().
i want this block of code working inside a method.

Comment: have you tried to debug your code to better understand where the error happens? It would be helpful, instead of having a huge chunk of code, to have the method or class where the error is.

Comment: at com.eguide.dimitris.campusguide.mainActivity$1.onVisitStart(mainActivity.java:66)

Thats where the error is....

Comment: ok, so you may do not need to have all your classes in your question. Please try to clean up your question a little bit to let us better understand where the problem is

Comment: Your `TextView` in `textFragment` should be initialized in `onCreateView()` method instead of `onActivityCreated()`

Comment: @Daniele  i cleaned button fragment...i think it was unnecessary...
Thnks for the advice

Comment: @Apurva i get an error when i do that....You know red underline...

Answer (score -1):

You need to make little change in your `textFragment`, initialize `TextView` in `onCreateView()` method as,

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.text_fragment, container,false);

    text1 = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textF);
    text1.setText("Press Start button to find buildings near you");

    return view;
}
```

Comment: Not working!!!!
@Apurva when i do this i get another error:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.eguide.dimitris.campusguide/com.eguide.dimitris.campusguide.mainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #35: Error inflating class fragment

-->

and ti points in this line of code in main Activity-->   setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

Comment: i made your answer work but it didnt solve my problem.Thanks though.